# Rolling back Visual Studio Extension to Earlier Version

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, web-essentials

How do I roll back a Visual Studio 2012 Extension to an earlier release?

I have just installed version 2.8 of (the excellent) Web Essentials, but I have found a problem with nested @import statements in this release (i.e. if one .less file @imports another .less file that itself @imports a .less file).  I have notified the author, but I need to be able to roll-back this extension to version 2.7 until the problem is resolved.

Is there a process/mechanism for achieving this?  I'm afraid I am not very familiar with git hub, or even how to find the earlier commit.

Comment: I have got the same issue. I hope they fix it soon as it is impairing my work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chocolatey has 2.7 version available (http://chocolatey.org/packages/WebEssentials2012), but at least in my case that just returned the newer 2.8 version.

I installed 2.5.6.2 version found from Mads nightly builds feed (http://madskristensen.net/post/Web-Essentials-nightly-builds.aspx) and that did the trick for me, @import -statements are working again.

Edit: 2.7 vsix package can be found from here: http://vswebessentials.com/nightly/webessentials2012-2.7.vsix

Comment: Thanks Absum.  The reversal to v 2.6 from http://vswebessentials.com/changelog has provided a workaround until the problem is fixed.  I also tried WinLESS that whilst not integrated into Visual Studio, worked great.